# Kohana Authlite authenticate and log in user after registration

Tags: authentication, kohana, kohana-3

I'm using the Kohana Authlite module for users authentication, and after a user registers I want them to be automatically logged in and eventually redirected to a page (that can be viewed only by logged in users.)

I'm trying the following piece of code:

```
$authlite = Authlite::instance('authlite');

$authlite->login($email, $user->password);

$this->redirect('Home');
```

But it doesn't work. Any idea or suggestions on how to make this happen?

Comment: What do you mean this doesn't work? What is expected vs what actually happens?

Comment: the user is not logged in, just redirected to home (in this case not a restricted page.but still, the user is not logged in. i guess i am using wrong the authlite class, but i can't figure out how else to use it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if `$user->password` isn't hashed. I'm guessing `$user` is instance of `ORM`, so `$user->password` is not password itself, but it's hash in database (in most cases). You need password in plain text for that.

Comment: I dont know about Authlite, but standard Auth module has a `force_login()` method for signing in without password value.

Comment: hmm... i take the password from post, because it is practically just after the user registers. About force login - do you think it is a good practice?

Comment: Yes, you take password from post, then you save it in database and afterwards you use `$user->password`. Well, at least I think so. Hence `$user->password` you're using might be hashed.